# What happens if someone steals an apple juice from a supermarket?

Tags: united-states, international, theft, france

I would like to know what is the risk if someone gets caught stealing a cheap item worth $1, such as an apple juice from a supermarket.

Comment: France and USA (I want to know in the 2 countries)

Comment: I get the impression that you are quite young. Would you like an answer that references that?

Comment: Yes I want it...

Comment: Are you an American stealing in France, or a French stealing in the US?

Comment: a French stealing in the US and in France (I want to know the 2 cases)

Comment: The short of the matter for any foreign visitor stealing, short of those with diplomatic immunity, is probably the best case scenario is that the vendor lets you go with a slap on the wrist and that's it, and the worst case scenario is that you're arrested, do time, get deported right at the end of your sentence, and be banned from legal re-entry for many years.  But that's an educated guess at the moment, maybe someone will provide a detailed analysis.

Comment: You should generally stick to one question per question, so asking about the penalties for doing this in both the US and France needs more focus.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: worst case is always death.  Either at the hands of those trying to apprehend the criminal or at the hands of their fellow criminals once incarcerated.

Comment: @jmoreno If you want to get that extreme then death is also the worst case of not stealing the apple juice.  Or doing anything at all.  We're just talking about legal consequences, not "how badly can the Universe screw you over at any given moment (Hint: the answer is maximally)".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: legally it can end up with you being killed and your death ruled not a murder. Citizens and police cannot be compelled to consider you a “safe” or “good” thief. And despite the jokes about club fed, we don’t have “jail for really nice people”.

Comment: From the stores fiscal handling, most retail stores have "product loss" budgeted into their books for just such cases.   Generally product loss covers things like "breakage, spoilage, and petty theft. So stores are economically budgeting in that of X apple juices they buy, Y will be lost when they make their purchase from the wholesaler.

Comment: It depends a lot on the color of your skin, in the U.S., even though it shouldn't. If you are black there is a non-negligible probability that you will be shot and killed.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you committed the crime in [nevada](/questions/tagged/nevada). Under [NRS 205.240](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/nrs-205.html#NRS205Sec240), this is a misdemeanor, petty larceny, the [maximum penalty for which](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/nrs-193.html#NRS193Sec150) is not more than 6 months in prison and a fine of not more than $1,000, plus restitution. [8 USC 1227](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1227) makes certain crimes deportable offenses, but shoplifting isn't one of them. In France, under [Art. 311-3 of the Code pénal](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000006070719/LEGISCTA000006117598/#LEGISCTA000006117598) the maximum penalty is 3 years and €45,000 fine. The "risk" is harder to calculate, if you mean "the most likely penalty". There is a substantial chance that the maximum penalty will be getting yelled at by the store manager, and even if you are arrested by the police there is a good chance that the matter (as a first offense, right? no aggravating circumstances) will not result in a trial because you will have the opportunity to "negotiate" the matter to probation, to avoid a trial. Rumor is that Walmart is aggressive in its anti-shoplifting policy.

Answer (score 4):

### Bad Idea ...

- The shopkeeper (or security employed by the shopkeeper) might not notice if you are clever, or they do notice. Don't bet on being more clever than professional security, it is their *job* to catch shoplifters. They do it all day.
- The shopkeeper or security guard might yell and come after you, and perhaps you manage to run away. But perhaps not. Again, it is the *job* of securty to catch shoplifters. They know the layout of the shop and the shortcuts.
- When you are caught, the shopkeeper will demand to see your receipt. It could all be a misunderstanding, after all. But if you don't have a receipt, they will think you are a thief.
- Then they can call the police. The police will usually come when they are called, no matter how low the value was, and record your ID and statements to the case. They could arrest you, or not.
- As user6726 pointed out, there is a good chance that the case will not go to trial, unless there are multiple prior arrests. But you might spend an afternoon being detained by the police while they sort that out and check your ID and record.